# Forward client ip with haproxy ssl passthrough

Tags: haproxy

I have haproxy doing ssl pass through communication with two httpd servers. I want to send the source ip of the client to the httpd servers.
I tried option forwardfor but it doesn't worked.

Haproxy version is 1.5.18 and the configuration is like this:

```
frontend localhttps
    bind *:443
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    option forwardfor
    default_backend httpsnodes

backend httpsnodes
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    balance source
    cookie SERVERID insert indirect 
    option ssl-hello-chk
    option forwardfor
    server <host1> <ip1> cookie 01 check
    server <host2> <ip2> cookie 02 check
```